# An easy version of Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma on $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

**Question**

Let $\left\{{\varepsilon}_{k}\right\}$ be an orthonormal set (it may be complete or not) in a Hilbert space $H$. Explain why for any $x \in H^{ \perp}$
$$
\lim _{k \rightarrow \infty}\left\langle x, {\varepsilon}_{k}\right\rangle=0
$$  Let $f \in L^{2}([-\pi, \pi]).$ Using the above fact show the following:
$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) \cos (n x  )dx=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) \sin (n x)dx=0
$$

---

I know that this is a rather easy version of Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma. However, I couldn't simply understand how to use the above fact. I'm open for any hint about reasoning to begin proving the claim.

Comment: Take $\varepsilon_k(x) = e^{ikx}$.

Comment: So we get something similar to Parseval's theorem proof.

Comment: The first line references $x\in H^\perp$, but $H^\perp=\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always have Bessel's inequality:
$$
            \sum_{n}|\langle x,e_n\rangle|^2 \le \|x\|^2.
$$
Therefore, you have a convergent sum, and the general term of a convergent sum always converges to $0$.